# For what estimated value of $x$ Is $|M(x)/\sqrt{x}|$ expected to exceed $1.2$ and $1.8$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Background:

Mertens conjecture stated that $-1 \lt \frac{M(x)}{\sqrt{x}} \lt 1$ when $x\gt 1$. [see more information here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_conjecture)

The conjecture was proved to be false in 1985 by showing $\liminf \frac{M(x)}{\sqrt{x}} \lt -1.009$ and $\limsup \frac{M(x)}{\sqrt{x}} \gt 1.006$. Later it was shown that this happened for some $x$ where $10^{16} \lt x \lt 10^{10^{40}}$.

In 2006 Kotnik improved the extremes to
$\liminf \frac{M(x)}{\sqrt{x}} \lt -1.2184 $ and $\limsup \frac{M(x)}{\sqrt{x}} \gt 1.2184$.

In 2017 Greg Hurst improved lower and upper bounds to $\liminf \frac{M(x)}{\sqrt{x}} \lt -1.837625 $ and $\limsup \frac{M(x)}{\sqrt{x}} \gt 1.826054$.

Question: is anything known about the estimates of $x$ for the first time these extremes found by Kotnik and Hurst are expected?